# How to Deny access to .class file from URL but allow from CI Application folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my HTACCESS file

How to Deny access to .class file from URL but allow from CI Application folder?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ci/


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]





    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]




    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```